# Ubuntu 16.04 - how to play a sound from script run from webservice, in background

Tags: sound, scripts, mp3, desktop-background, sh

I am a developper, and have configured a server on ubuntu 16.04, running web services.

Those web services are calling some script file locally 
the script is doing some task, and should play a sound when task are completed.

The problem is that the script is called, the tasks are done, but the sound is not played.

Here is my checklist:

- The sound is working fine and properly configured on the computer.
- If I call my script from terminal command line, the tasks are done, and the sound is played.
- If I call the script from the web service, the tasks are done, but the sound is not played.

Here is an example of what I have tested:

```bash
# script name : eject.sh
# ... here I do some stuff, which are working fine...
play -q /mnt/datas/wifi_started.mp3 >/dev/null
cvlc --play-and-exit /mnt/datas/wifi_started.mp3 &>/dev/null &
nohup mplayer /mnt/datas/wifi_started.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

All of the lines above are playing sound when the script file is executed from terminal, and no sound when executed from web service!

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: What kind of web service are you running? I tested by logging in via `ssh` and it works (but the sound is at the server, not at the client). Do you want to sound to be transferred to the client?

Answer (score 0):

## Updated answer

The sound should be played at the server, but the problem is that it will only play, if a user is logged in.

I tested this in test systems of Lubuntu and Xubuntu Bionic (that I am testing anyway). I installed `openssh-server` and `espeak` (and in Xubuntu-Core and Ubuntu you need also the program package `gnome-system-tools` to get the program `users-admin`).

Then there is an easy fix:

1. Select **Use audio devices** in **`users-admin`**
2. Press **<kbd>OK</kbd>**.

You may need to move the window (with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left mouse button</kbd>) to find the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

[image]

Then it works while still at the log in screen to play sound via `ssh` and I would guess also via other web services,

```
ssh tester@192.168.0.10 "espeak 'Hello while still at the log in screen'"
```

Modify the userID and network address to match your case.

To make things smooth (with `ssh`) you should log in with keys, but I don't know if that is a problem with *your* web service.

I hope this can help you play a sound that you can hear when the tasks in the server are completed.

## Original answer

#### Assuming `ssh` and the sound to be played at the client

If you log in via `ssh` the sound is at the server, not at the client. I guess that you want the sound to be transferred to the client.

- It is possible to transfer the sound to the client, but it is not straight-forward. Maybe you will find something useful, when you browse the internet with the following search string, **linux sound at client**. I think I did (but did not test it).
- But there is a workaround, that is simpler. Run the tasks at the server such that you can play the sound locally in your client, when the tasks have finished.

**Example:**

`openssh-server` is installed in my workstation and I can connect to it from any other computer via my local network.

Install `espeak`,

```
sudo apt install espeak
```

The following shellscript illustrates what happens,

```
ssh sudodus@192.168.0.2 \
"echo 'Who am I to do this?'| tee /dev/stderr |espeak; whoami| \
tee /dev/stderr |espeak| tee /dev/stderr |espeak;\
echo 'At which server?'| tee /dev/stderr |espeak;hostname -A| tee /dev/stderr|espeak"

sleep 1

echo 'Who am I to check this?'| tee /dev/stderr |espeak; whoami| tee /dev/stderr |espeak
echo 'At which client?' | tee /dev/stderr |espeak
hostname -A| tee /dev/stderr |espeak
```

This is the written output from a live drive with Lubuntu.

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ ./tasks-at-server_reported-at-client 
sudodus@192.168.0.2's password: 
Who am I to do this?
sudodus
At which server?
xw8400 
Who am I to check this?
lubuntu
At which client?
lubuntu 
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

If you can hear both computers, you will hear the server 'speak' and after that hear the client 'speak'. Otherwise you will hear the client 'speak'.

Comment: Hello,thank you but I need to play the sound on the linux computer side, not on the client side ( which is a tablet ). The user click on some button on the tablet, web service are called, on serveur side ( the linux computer ) some scripts are run. in order to tell to the user that job is done, I need to play sound. The serveur is a local server, let say a Box, that the user brind with him and with the tablet. there is no keyboard, no monitor, so I need to play sound on server side.

Comment: When you use the `ssh` service, the sound is played on the server. *What service are you using?* Maybe the problem is with your particular web service. - As a first step you might check if you can use the method in my answer (with `ssh` from a PC rather than from a tablet) and later on modify it to run your script to do its tasks and then play a sound when started remotely via `ssh` and later try to find out how to do the corresponding things, so that it is useful for your purpose.

Comment: the web service is something called by the apache server.

Comment: I tested the use of espeak, it produce no sound when the scipt is called from the web service. The problem is that there is only the sound job which is not done, all other task are done properly by the script.

Comment: if someone want to test it, I have exactly the same issue if I try to play a sound, before I login on the ubuntu server : at the screen where the user need to enter its password.

Comment: This is a difference from my server (which is actually a work-station, where I have installed `openssh-server` to make it a server in my home network). My server is playing sound and doing tasks via `crontab` also before log in, when I modify `PATH` to find what needs to be found `@reboot` in `crontab` for `root`.

Comment: I started Xubuntu in a test computer and installed `openssh-server` and `espeak`. You are right, that you must login to hear for example `espeak 'Hello World'`. But it works with elevated permissions also without login (while at the login screen). Try this command line from a client (modified to your userID and network address), `ssh -X tester@192.168.0.10 "xterm -e sudo espeak 'Hello via x term'"` . It is not convenient, but should be possible to fix, so that you need not enter a password (I don't know now, how to do it).

Comment: There is an easy fix for this:  Select 'Use audio devices' in `users-admin` and press OK. Then it works while still at the log in screen to play sound via the `ssh` and I would guess also via other web services: `ssh tester@192.168.0.10 "espeak 'Hello while still at the log in screen'"`

Comment: @OlivierRobin, there are more details in the updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the details. I don't know, today, how I will be able to discuss using an ipad, in ssh to the linux server. I need to investigate if it is possible by my iPad application.

Comment: another remark, but it is not a big deal, I cannot connect to server, from my ipad, using ssh in my Application. in my ubuntu, there is no advenced user settings available at all. thanks anyway for the time soent on helping me.

Comment: @OlivierRobin, Install the program package `gnome-system-tools` to get the program `users-admin` installed in your Ubuntu.