# Crontab doesn't work when I sign out

Tags: sound, encryption, cron

I just installed the latest Lubuntu 18.04. After installing and configuring the system, I find that my crontab runs when I am signed in. My crontab basically plays a song at a certain time. When I sign out, it doesn't execute. I did some reading on the internet and most people suggest if the folder is encrypted, cronjob can't run. However, my folder is not encrypted. I look for the .encrypt file/folder, it's not there.

Then I try to ssh into the machine and play a song from the console. No sound comes out of the pc. But when I sign into the pc, the sound emerges from the speaker. In other words, the command works in SSH, but the audio doesn't come out of the speaker. Any advice?

I ran crontab -e and made my entries as user account. Not sudo crontab -e

Best wishes,
Sathesh.

Comment: Let's start by figuring out what part is the problem, is it sound or crontab. Setup a crontab to touch a file, sign out and see if it runs. I suspect this is a pulseaudio issue rather than crontab

Comment: If you use `sudo crontab -e` you will get the system's crontab, and it will run also when you have signed out from your regular user. If you want sound when connected via `ssh`, you should allow the user to 'use audio devices'. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027836/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-play-a-sound-from-script-run-from-webservice-in-backgroun/1027918#1027918)